# Error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I have a base class called `CellModel` like this

```
public class CellModel{
   public init<T>(cell: T.Type, selectionHandler: SelectionHandler) where T: Cell, T: CellType
   {
      //anything here
   }
}
```

and a class named `CustomCellModel` like this

```
public class CustomCellModel: CellModel{
    init(title: String, selectionHandler: SelectionHandler) {

    self.title = title
    super.init(cell: CustomCell.self, selectionHandler: selectionHandler)
    }
}
```

And CustomCell is like this

```
public class CustomCell: CellType, Cell {

}
```

At the line calling `super.init` in `CustomCellModel` `init` method I am receiving a compile-time error

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I don't know what is wrong about this.

**Update:**

By help of @Hamish I could finally resolve this problem by changing my subclass init method by adding `@escaping` to `selectionHandler` parameter like this

```
public class CustomCellModel: CellModel{
    init(title: String, selectionHandler: @escaping SelectionHandler) {

    self.title = title
    super.init(cell: CustomCell.self, selectionHandler: selectionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `CustomCell`? Does it conform to/inherit from `Cell` and `CellType`?

Comment: Yes it conforms to CellType, Cell

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could boil this down to a [mcve]. How is `SelectionHandler` defined?

Comment: What are Cell and CellType? Protocols or classes?

Comment: @Hamish
I think it's about `SelectionHandler`
when I remove `selectionHandler` from init method, it compiles successfully.
It is defined like this

`public typealias SelectionHandler = (Cell) -> ()`

Comment: @HassanEskandari Ah, that'll be the problem then – you need to mark it as `@escaping` for the subclass' `init` parameter, as it's escaping the lifetime of the `init` method.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you, adding `@escaping` solves the problem.
The error was misleading, but I think we have to get used to these types of error from swift compiler :|

Comment: @HassanEskandari Yeah, unfortunately there are still many edge cases with the compiler's diagnostics, which output completely useless error messages.